# GWT action Cell Rounded Corner?

Tags: css, gwt

I want my Action cell[Button] to have curved rounded corners. Currently I use the following CSS:

```
background-color:#002A50;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    width:65px;
    height:15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
```

But the corners are still not rounded. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

use this css property for rounded borders.
`border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;`

 remove `border: none;` this property will show no borders

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to your CSS snippet.